# Conditional expression in symbolic Matlab

Tags: matlab

If we do the following,

```
function [z] = a(x,y)
syms x y
If I do the following code,
if x>5
    z=x+y
else
    z=x-y
end
end
```

then I hope to have something like (as in Mathematica)

```
z=IF[x>5,x+y,x-y]
```

I do not insist on having the exact same code as above. I am flexible. I just want to have "just one line" which expresses how input of function results in output when there are if in the code.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Matlab does not support tertiary operator i.e. `a = b ? c : d`. However there is a hacky way of getting the same result.

```
z = (x>5)*(x+y) + (x<=5)*(x-y)
```